# MonacaバックエンドのユーザログインAPIの仕様について

Tags: monaca

OnsenUI、Monaca バックエンド API を使用して、ログイン後、ボタンを押すとバックエンドのコレクションにアイテムが追加されるアプリを作成しています。

ログイン後に `monaca.cloud.User._oid` を使ってユーザの OID を取得しようとしましたが、`NULL` が入っています。ログイン後はアプリ内ではログイン状態が維持されないのでしょうか。

Answer (score 1):

ログイン処理は非同期なので、.then()以下で取得を試みれば、取得できるはずです。自分のサンプルコードを提示します。よければ、動かしてみてください。最小限のテンプレートを編集して作成したものです。

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
    <script src="components/loader.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="components/loader.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <script>

        document.addEventListener('deviceready', onDR, false);

        function onDR() {
            alert('deviceready come!');
            monaca.cloud.User.login("hoge", "hogehoge")
                .then(function() {
                    alert(monaca.cloud.User._oid);
                });
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```